# HTTP Request returning empty element

Tags: json, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I try to get a JSON object from a webservice with

```
MashupPlatform.http.makeRequest(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            requestHeaders: {"Accept": "application/json"},
            forceProxy: true,
            onSuccess: function (response) {
                console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
                success(response);
            },
            onFailure: function (response) {
                error(response);
            },
            onComplete: function () {
                complete();
            }
        });
```

but in the console every time an empty element (`{}`) gets logged. If I use curl to request that exact same URL I get the response I need. Is the wirecloud proxy unable to request application/json? In my browsers network analysis I see the request including the correct response, but the success function seems to not get that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WireCloud proxy supports `application/json` without any problem. Although the problem may be caused by other parameters, I think that your problem is related to a bad access to the response data. You should use `response.responseText` instead of using directly the response object (see this [link](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.org/en/stable/widgetapi/widgetapi/#response-object) for more info).